# How to rotate display orientation on Odroid XU4 Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xorg, odroid

How can i rotate display orientation on Odroid XU4 running Ubuntu 16.04? I want to make portrait mode. Is it even possible for this Odroid?

Comment: Hi,I am also interested in odroid xu4 board,could you please share the reference path used for board bring up

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu you can rotate the screen with `xrandr` command.

Example

`xrandr -o left`

`xrandr -o right`

`xrandr -o inverted`

`xrandr -o normal`

Comment: Try deleting `etc/X11/xorg.conf`, restart and try the command

Comment: did what you suggested, but got the same issue

Comment: Very sorry for such a late reply.
Try the command `xrandr -q`, this would list all the connected monitors.

Comment: Once that is found out, you can try
`xrandr --output <Display Name> --rotate right`

Comment: I flashed arch linux image on sd card. xranrd -o left works with arch nicely .

Answer (score 0):

The exynos 5422 has no rotating scanout hardware. Xrandr usually only exposes the interface to change scanout hardware orientation.
There have been patches for the drm to change the drm engine to be able to chain the hardware scaler/rotators to the drm, which would be able to do roughly the same, but for now those has been rejected.
There is one Xorg driver implementation that actually does it in software, that's the intel driver, since the smallest intel SoC's have no changeable scanout hardware.

So if you want to rotate, you end up with making your software rotate (chromium is plain html at no rendering costs), or use compton-gl compositor and let the compositor rotate (costs gles and memory bandwidth), use Samsung's patches, or try to fix the Xorg driver...

I mean: if the intel can do it, armsoc should be able to do it too.